# How to creat and read databse in actionscript3 ( ini or sql )?

Tags: sql, database, actionscript-3, ini

I need a way to create a swf application that creates a file in the same folder that my swf will be and to be able to read and write stuff on it so i can have a "save" file.

I wanna know if that's possible and the easiest way for me to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

About the database, you have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262679/flash-cs4-sqlite) and also a positive answer, hope will help you.
To save your file you will need to use the [File API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("myFileName.txt");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes("This is my text file.");
stream.close();
```